# How to prevent from multiple IAP requests?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, alert, restriction

I have a button that requests an IAP to remove ads. How do I restrict it to be only pressed once so that the IAP alert view does not popup more than once.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like `button.enabled = NO` called in your IBAction?